# how to code a java method that retrieve a given index value?

Tags: java, oop, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

// this this the orginal code:

```
public void searchBird (int indexPosition) {
    Bird bird = birdList.get(indexPosition);
    System.out.println ("Art:" + bird.getArt ());
    System.out.println ("Location:" + bird.getLocation ());
}
```

I have so far tried to code a method which returns one element out 
    of the ArrayList with a given index as a parameter. I get an error 
    message when I send in, for example 5, as a parameter.

```
// and this is what i tried:

public void searchBird (int indexPosition) {
    Bird bird = birdList.get(indexPosition);
    for (int i = 0; i <bird list.size (); i ++) {
        if ((birdList.contains(indexPosition))) {
            System.out.println ("Art:" + bird.getArt ());
            System.out.println ("Location:" + bird.getLocation ());
        }
    }
}
```

this is what i get;

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 3
>   when calling the method with 5 as a parameter

Comment: Please translate the complete question to english

Comment: Please verify the code you posted. Your if statement `for (int i = 0; i <bird list.size (); i ++) {` can not work. The space between `bird` and `list` seems wrong to me. Please check.

Comment: Your array has 3 items and you are trying to get the 6th item in it.. Check if the size is smaller than given index and return gracefully

Comment: Sorry for that, i have translate it now @jhamon

Comment: If `birdList` is a list of `Bird` objects, why would you expect it to contain `indexPosition`, an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if the given index (`indexPosition`) is valid in your `birdList`.
If you give an index that is larger than the last index of the list, then you get the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you have seen.

Try a little check before calling `birdList.get(indexPosition)` and skip the entire `for` loop, you don't need it. Additionally, you should not pass an index to the `contains` method because it looks for objects, not for indexes (if you have a defined `Bird`, you can try `birdList.contains(bird)`).

```
public void searchBird(int indexPosition) {
    // there might be the following case: indexPosition > maximum index of birdList
    if (indexPosition < birdList.size()) {
        Bird bird = birdList.get(indexPosition);
        System.out.println("Art:" + bird.getArt());
        System.out.println("Location:" + bird.getLocation());
    } else {
        System.out.println("The given index exceeds the list of birds!");
    }
}
```

Comment: That should have bothered you: `if (birdList.contains(indexPosition))`

Comment: Yes, you are right... I will adjust my answer accordingly! Thanks!

Comment: @dehaar thank you so much for your help , your answer was really helpful and the method works good now!

Comment: @SadeerThaer No problem, you are welcome.